# Notifications when a post is moved or deleted

Tags: feature-request, notifications, email

Hello Stackoverflow Team,

I suggest that you build into the forum system a mail notifier(to notify users whenever there is a move/deletion of a post with the reason of the move/deletion) so that whenever you move or removed someone's post then he can be notified about the move, so that we don't spend time looking for posts that are removed.

I think by so doing the number of duplicate posts and mistakes from users can be minimized.

The reason is I spent hours searching through the posts to locate my posts that you have re/moved. That is why i was a little bit upset.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ is the right place to post this kind off question (suggestions in your case).

Comment: Note that this post is going to be moved, consider this comment as an email :)

Comment: I have often wondered if users are aware of where a post is migrated to. I haven't had any migrated, so I don't know what the process is.

Comment: @dboarman When a post is migrated, the address of the trilogy site links to the destination post directly. Likewise, the destination post links back to the original (try clicking on the "stackoverflow.com" in the "migrated from stackoverflow.com" message below).

Comment: @ccornet: ah...very nice. Given this linkage, I don't really see any need for the email notification.

Answer (score 2):

Click your own name at the top (next to the envelope).

[alt text http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/6845/screenshot20100507at224.png](http://img32.imageshack.us/img32/6845/screenshot20100507at224.png)

That should give you a quick way to your own questions (including closed / moved).

Comment: nice - freehand circle and arrows...

Comment: -1 free hand circle border is too thin

Comment: @Downvoter: good point, I've updated the freehand circle ;-)